# Can gnu diff recursively compare only filenames in different folder structures?

Tags: linux, command-line, bash, diff

I know that I can recursively compare two dirs with `diff -qr` and output only the differences. However, this appears to compare file positions within the trees (for example, `/a/b/file01 != /b/c/file01`).

I want to compare two differing trees and result only unique files (regardless of their position in the tree). So in the above example, `file01` would be considered a match. Is this possible with `diff`, or do I have to do a nested `find` loop and iterate through each one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would use `find` and some shenanigans:

Lets say the two paths are /a and /b:

```
find /a/ /b/ -exec basename \{} \; | sort | uniq -u
```

So this is "find all files in /a and /b, and output their basenames (ie, path removed), then sort them, then output any unique values in the list".

If you then want to find where these files are in the directories, we can wrap the whole thing in a loop and find them:

```
for i in `find /a/ /b/ -exec basename \{} \; | sort | uniq -u`; do find /a/ /b/ -name $i; done
```

Comment: This works perfectly for me because I know which dir tree is missing files. If there were unique records in both trees, a different approach might be needed. (I don't think `uniq` is aware of direction.)

Comment: @kiwisan I have updated the answer to include finding the files after you find them :).  Actually, my test files didn't include any spaces, so the `$i` might well need quoting.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it's possible with `diff`. I presume you are thinking of something along the lines of:

```
find tree1 -type f | while f=`line` ; do diff $f `find tree2 -type f -name "${f##*/}"`; done
```

(This needs elaborating to allow for multiple or no instances in `tree2` of each file from `tree1`, and for embedded blanks.)

What you can do to speed it up is to save the file list in `tree2` first:

```
find tree2 -type f >tree2.list
find tree1 -type f | while f=`line` ; do diff $f `grep <tree2.list "/${f##*/}$"`; done
```

This means for each file, instead of searching a directory hierarchy, only a single file is scanned.